# Работа с вводом-выводом в ffmpeg

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

Второй день борюсь с проблемой обрезки моментов и наложения эффекта "размытие" в ffmpeg из под c#.
Вот мой код запуска процесса:

```
 _ffmpegProc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            FileName = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
```

Вот код ввода-вывода через потоки:

```
using (Stream inpt = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        inpt.CopyTo(_ffmpegProc.StandardInput.BaseStream);
        _ffmpegProc.StandardInput.Close();
    }

    var response = Array.Empty<byte>();
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _ffmpegProc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(output);
        response = output.ToArray();
    }
```

1. Проблема возникает когда я хочу обрезать видео, а именно
   как только я меняю /path/to/save.mp4 на -f mp4 pipe:1 сразу вылезает ошибка

> System.IO.IOException: Connection timed out
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Connection timed out

Вот аргумент который я использую для обрезки фрагментов видео:

```
var arg =
        $"-i pipe:0 -ss 00:01:05 -to 00:03:10 -c copy pipe:1";
return StartFfmpeg(arg, input);
```

2. Аналогичная ошибка и с блюром.
   Аргумент размытия:

> "-lavfi [0:v]scale=256/81*iw:256/81*ih,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h,w)/40:luma_power=3:chroma_radius=min(cw,ch)/40:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,setsar=1,crop=w=iw*81/256";